# How to compress pictures with jquery file uploader

Tags: jquery, image, jquery-file-upload, image-compression

I'm using jquery-File-Upload (https://github.com/blueimp/jQuery-File-Upload) and it is working. It is creating even thumbs.

But I have one problem. I want to compress the pictures but dont know how to do it.

Any ideas? Thank you!

Answer (score -2):

Wiki is your friend! Was searching for compression. The keyword is quality.

https://github.com/blueimp/jQuery-File-Upload/wiki/Options#imagequality :)